# "Related" links in comments

Tags: discussion

I often see comments on questions which just say

> [Related](//)

and link to another question. What's the point? When should I add links like this?

Comment: Note: my primary purpose is posting this self-answered question is to save from repeating myself every time someone responds to one of these links with an argument for why it's not a dupe, but I have no objection to a broader discussion on the purpose of these links and the situations in which to use them or not.

Comment: I agree with this meta post, but I don't think people replying to you saying "that's not a dupe" are necessarily arguing. Many times, they're just pointing out differences.  It does save some people the time to click through and read them both themselves.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12110/related-links-in-comments)

Answer (score 15):

The sidebar on a question has a section under the heading "Related" which links to other questions and is generated automatically based on searching for similar words. But questions which are explicitly linked are pulled to the top under the heading "Linked".

In most sites in the StackExchange network these links have a dual purpose, along the lines of "If you found this question and its answers useful, you might find these useful too; and if it wasn't quite what you were looking for, maybe one of these is". PPCG breaks the mould a bit, but fundamentally the sidebar still functions as a recommendation system.

Therefore the purpose of these "Related" links in comments is to highlight the questions from the "Related" sidebar which are most relevant (either as potentially sharing techniques, or as potentially interesting to the same people), or to add questions which aren't picked up by word similarity.

Note that the point is *not* to claim that the question is a dupe, borderline dupe, or near dupe. In that case, the comment should say so explicitly.

Comment: I guess there's a secondary purpose to *help* the active users with dupe searches. When there's a new challenge on a theme that can be phrased in a bunch of ways it's sometimes hard to find all the related challenges via the search, but if you can find one of them, and then follow a trail of sidebar links to the various takes on the given theme, it's usually easier to find out if that exact version of the theme has been done before or not.